# The acceptance of eye care services among patients "is likely to be high" or "will potentially be high or higher"

Tags: word-choice

In the above sentence, my confusion is words after patients " **is likely to be high" or "will potentially be high or higher"**.

is it correct and which one will be more appropriate?

Comment: Both are possible depending on the context and what you mean. You have given no context. Your question cannot be answered.

Comment: Hospital Rehabilitation (HR) should make a network with community Based organizations (CBOs). Since, CBOs provide disability oriented services, the acceptance of HR among patients is likely to be high or will be potentially be high

Comment: Thank you. However your context requires several corrections, and unfortunately, EL&U does not do proofreading. "**is likely to be high**" = will probably be high. "**will, potentially, be high**" [*note the commas]* = will possibly have the ability to be high." *(You should not use "higher" unless you are comparing it with something.)*